# Print Horizontal Line in Ruby

Tags: ruby, printing, printf, puts

Can ruby's puts or print draw horizontal line kind of like bash does with printf+tr does ?

```
printf '%20s\n' | tr ' ' -
```

this will draw:

```
--------------------
```

Comment: @Felix Wait, so you mean to tell me that you, can't just do this in ruby using the standard library?

Comment: OK, I missed the point. I was referring to curses because I thought you wanted a line without "spaces".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a quick `puts "*"*80` for debug purposes. I'm sure there are better ways.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following snippet

```
puts "-"*20
```

Check [this](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-2A) for more help.

You might be interested in formatting using [ljust](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-ljust), [rjust](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-rjust) and [center](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-center) as well.

Comment: Just asking, doesn't ruby have something like `"{0:^20}".format(var)` like in Python?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac The output of the snippet you mention is `'         -          '` which is not what the OP needs. But `print("-" * 20)` should work in python as well.

Comment: I realize that, but if you ask something a little more specific, then you you are broke. For example, if you wanted to fill up empty spaces with `-` and you have some string to format it with, then you're stuck. In python, its easy as `"{0:-^20}".format("END OF TASK")`.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac in ruby you can do this by `"END OF TASK".ljust(20,"-")` or `rjust` depending on the side you want to fill

Answer (score 1):

For fancy lines:

```
p 'MY_LINE'.center(80,'_-')
#=> "_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-MY_LINE_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also have the following:

```
puts "".center(20, "-")

irb(main):005:0> puts "".center(20, '-')
=> "--------------------"
```

This could be more flexible if you wanted to add additional information:

```
irb(main):007:0> puts "end of task".center(20, "-")
----end of task-----
=> nil
```

Comment: +1 Was about to reply with the same in comments to my answer, but then saw your answer. FWIW, the link in my answer has documentation for `.center`, `.ljust` and `.rjust` as well.

Comment: @ansh0l I researched and found it out. I got a terrible bashing from the chat room guys though :P

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`String#ljust`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-ljust) or [`String#rjust`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-rjust).

```
puts ''.rjust(20,"-")
# >> --------------------
puts ''.ljust(20,"-")
# >> --------------------
```